# Why use both an overflow menu and a hardware settings button menu to show the same options?

Tags: android

This kind of behaviour appears on devices that have a hardware settings button (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S3). Apps like Hangouts or Slack use both an overflow menu and the menu that appears when pressing the hardware settings button.

Using an overflow button to show exactly the same options as the hardware settings button menu seems redundant to me. It also seems like it stands against best practices. Because such behaviour appears in many popular apps, I think this might confuse the regular user a little bit.

Is this to make the user's transition to newer versions of the Android platform easier? 
Is it recommended to implement the options menu this way for such devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose so it depends. Even an Samsung G5 or G6 have a hardware menu. Press the multi tasking window for a long time. It does the same as pressing an overflow button. This is so that the uses of older versions of Android can use there accustomed way of using the menu button. This simply provides your app with a richer User experience.

Especially value of minimum SDK version is very low it is recommended to use this to provide a richer User experience to your application. It is your wish as to how the app is supposed to workm